# Gift tax on gifts from multiple, unrelated individuals

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, gifts

Based on my “pay no tax” research I found this gift law. I think I’m on the right track and would like clarification because, I literally detest the government for very good reasons; not the least of which their employees murdered my son and destroyed my family without consequence. So, to give them even one penny is unacceptable to me.

Can I teach children an invaluable skill for free and provide a website or PayPal link for anyone who appreciates the result of my gift to their child and wishes to gift me money (or maybe they don’t have a child but believe in my revolutionary contribution to the future) as they see fit, up to $10K?

Comment: It was tax fraud when you answered it in a previous question, and it's tax fraud now when you ask it stand-alone.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I teach children an invaluable skill for free and provide a website or PayPal link for anyone who appreciates the result of my gift to their child and wishes to gift me money (or maybe they don’t have a child but believe in my revolutionary contribution to the future) as they see fit, up to $10K?

Two immediately obvious problems with this strategy:

1. What about when you receive gifts from people who aren't in the US? You have to declare, and pay taxes on, foreign gifts.
2. It seems to me that these may not be gifts because they are given in connection with the service you provided rather than from "detached and disinterested generosity" as required to make the gift tax exempt. (See Commisioner v. Duberstein -- gift given to thank associate for a sales lead did not arise from detached generosity. See Stanton v. United States -- gift given in appreciation of services rendered may or may not be a gift for tax purposes. See also Bogardus v. Commissioner -- gifts inspired by past service can be tax exempt.)